# How can I have two objects aligned horizontally (one to the right of the other) and center the left one?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form which looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="query"/>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and I want the input to be horizontally centered in the page and then I would like the button to be aligned with it horizontally and placed to the right of the input element. How do I do this?

I have tried making them both display: inline-block and centering the input but I can't get it to work.

Also I am using bootstrap if that helps/doesn't. 
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/k6bot5mu/1/) is a fiddle of the whole thing

Comment: give both input and button `float:left` you can also try to give a certain width to both of them. Object ths should be centered is the form-group element - try to do that with `margin:auto`

Comment: Thanks! I added a fiddle of the html/css and tried your suggestion, but without specifying the width it spills to the left.

Comment: Does it work with the width?
if you're using boostrap you can `col-md-12` to form-group class and then `col-md-6` both to the input and the button classes

Comment: It does work with the width's that Kornik posted about in his answer, but not using the columns you suggest. It makes the input take up half the horizontal length and the button take the other half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the table layout on `.form-group` to shrink it on its content and center it via `margin`:

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.form-group{
  display:table;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

input, button{
float: left;
}
/* optionnal to take button off from center calculation */

/* demo purpose */
html:hover button {
  position:absolute;
  }

body {
  min-height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, lightgray 50%);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="query" class="searchbar same-line centered"/>
        <button type="submit" class="same-line">Search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

to keep button off center, you may use padding and absolute :

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.form-group{
  display:table;
 margin: 0 auto;
  padding:0 5em;/* to keep button in sight if window comes very small */
}

input, button{
float: left;
}

button {
  position:absolute;
  }

body {
  min-height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, lightgray 50%);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="query" class="searchbar same-line centered"/>
        <button type="submit" class="same-line">Search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to float: left; both input and submit button and add a width to your form. to center them horizontally just margin: 0 auto to your form.

like this:

```
<div class="container">
<form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="query"/>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
 width: 800px;
 background: #000;
}

form{
 width: 200px;
 background: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

input, button{
width: 50px;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I get it to work with different widths? using percentages? You solution works with the width you posted, i tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/k6bot5mu/1/, but using different widths/ not specifying widths it always spills to the left. Sorry if this is obvious, but i'm new to css/html

Comment: yes you could always use percents. but take note, the width of input and button should fit inside the width of the form. and in order for margin 0 auto to work and center the element it should have a width also with also also the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I gathered that you only wanted the input centered with the button sitting to the right. The other answers simply center both elements. This example uses bootstrap columns to center the input and place the button to the right. It is responsive to the window size and expands in width as the window gets smaller.

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post" class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/rawiki/pen/PzNZwz

Answer (score 0):

I removed your code and added these small changes, only modified your CSS, using `margin-top` of the button.

```
button {
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
form * {
  margin: 10px, 10px, 10px;
}
input {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```